# Method 'load' does not work bootstrap-table

Tags: json, ajax, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to load data and popular a table bootstrap-table through an ajax call, but it does not work with the load method. Trying the data method works normally.

the method is not starting, it also does not display that no result was found

**Table**

```
<table id="table-anexo" class="table table-striped table-hover display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th data-field="id"><span>DOCUMENTO</span></th>
             <th data-field="tipo"><span>TIPO</span></th>
             <th data-field="dt_anexo"><span>DATA ANEXO</span></th>
         <!--<th data-field="acao" data-formatter="" data-events="" ><span>AÇÃO</span></th>-->
        </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**Function AJAX**

```
function get_anexo_ajax(metodo, editando_id) {
    var ticket_id = editando_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {ticket_id : ticket_id},
        url: 'ticket/get_anexo_all',
        success: (function (data) {
            console.log(data.anexo);          
            //$('#table-anexo').bootstrapTable({ data: data.anexo });
            //$('#table-anexo').bootstrapTable('refresh')
            $('#table-anexo').bootstrapTable('load', data.anexo);
        }),
    });
}
```

**Data JSON**

```
{"anexo":[{"id":"1","tipo":"jpg","dt_anexo":"2018-08-01 11:09:28","mensagem_id":"2","ticket_id":"1"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think data is the invalid format. And Set data-toggle="table" on a normal table. I tested, it run Ok. You can try:

```
<table id="table-anexo" data-toggle="table" class="table table-striped table-hover display" style="width:100%">

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#table-anexo').bootstrapTable('load', obj.anexo);
```

Comment: Tanks! I also thought it might be this, but JSON is already an object.
I could see that using the load method, the table does not start.
even using: `$('#table-anexo').bootstrapTable('load', [])`;

Comment: @WagnerFilho: I updated my answer. Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Hi thank you very much, my friend!!
It worked for me now.

Comment: @WagnerFilho: Yeah! You're so great, my friend :))